# Disable Test with Spring and Junit5 without context creation

Tags: spring, junit5

We recently migrated our test framework to JUnit5 and are having some issues using `@Disabled` (und `ExecutionCondition`s) in tests which are using `@SpringJUnitConfig`:
In Junit4 `@Ignore` disabled the test execution without question and without executing anything. With Junit5 and `@Disabled`, the system now creates the spring context *before* realizing that the test should not be executed. In our case this leads to disabled tests failing, because some of them are disabled because the context cannot be created under some circumstances.

Is it possible to disable a test (class) in JUnit5 in a way that no spring context is created for this test?

Minimal example:

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) // To support tests running in eclipse 
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = {BaseTestSpringTest.TestConfiguration.class})
@Disabled
public class BaseTestSpringTest {

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.package" })
    public class TestConfiguration {
    }

    @Component
    public class TestClass {
        @PostConstruct
        public void fail() {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    protected TestClass test;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `@EnabledIf` or `@DisabledIf` from Spring 5, then the `ApplicationContext` should not be eagerly loaded.

Comment: With regard to usage of `@Disabled` from JUnit Jupiter, I'd have to see exactly (1) what used to work with JUnit 4 and (2) what doesn't work now with JUnit Jupiter (JUnit 5).

Comment: Can you please provide examples for JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter? TIA!

Comment: We have tests which use @Autowired beans. These beans have `@PostConstructs` that fail, so we used `@Ignore` on the test class with JUnit4 which caused them to be skipped without any discussion(/context creation). In other words: With Junit4 I have never seen a `@Ignore` test fail, with Junit5 and `@Disabled` it happend in quite a few cases

Comment: Since I am the author of the `SpringExtension` I would really like to get to the bottom of this!

Comment: Can you please post an example of what is failing in JUnit Jupiter with the `SpringExtension`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I created an added a condensed example.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Comment: If you comment out `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` then the test will be disabled without an exception, as you would expect.

Comment: Thus, this appears to actually be a _bug_ in JUnit Jupiter with regard to test class instantiation vs. disabled test classes. I'll investigate further and report back.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this earlier just noticed the `@TestInstance` myself when putting together this example (we had this "hidden" within our test class hierarchy). Thanks for investigating!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in JUnit Jupiter that only occurs when using the `PER_CLASS` test instance lifecycle mode.

I have raised the following issue in the JUnit 5 issue tracker to address this issue. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1103

Comment: The issue has been resolved in master and is fixed in the latest 5.1.0-SNAPSHOT version.